# Best way to store data for Greasemonkey based crawler?

Tags: persistence, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey, storage, web-crawler

I want to crawl a site with Greasemonkey and wonder if there is a better way to temporarily store values than with GM_setValue.

What I want to do is crawl my contacts in a social network and extract the Twitter URLs from their profile pages.

My current plan is to open each profile in it's own tab, so that it looks more like a normal browsing person (ie css, scrits and images will be loaded by the browser). Then store the Twitter URL with GM_setValue. Once all profile pages have been crawled, create a page using the stored values.

I am not so happy with the storage option, though. Maybe there is a better way?

I have considered inserting the user profiles into the current page so that I could all process them with the same script instance, but I am not sure if XMLHttpRequest looks indistignuishable from normal user initiated requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a similar project where I needed to get a whole lot of (invoice line data) from a website, and export it into an accounting database.

You could create a .aspx (or PHP etc) back end, which processes POST data and stores it in a database.

Any data you want from a single page can be stored in a form (hidden using style properties if you want), using field names or id's to identify the data. Then all you need to do is make the form action an .aspx page and submit the form using javascript.

(Alternatively you could add a submit button to the page, allowing you to check the form values before submitting to the database).

Answer (score 2):

I think you should first ask yourself why you want to use Greasemonkey for your particular problem. Greasemonkey was developed as a way to modify one's browsing experience -- not as a web spider. While you might be able to get Greasemonkey to do this using GM_setValue, I think you will find your solution to be kludgy and hard to develop. That, and it will require many manual steps (like opening all of those tabs, clearing the Greasemonkey variables between runs of your script, etc).

Does anything you are doing require the JavaScript on the page to be executed? If so, you may want to consider using Perl and [WWW::Mechanize::Plugin::JavaScript](http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/WWW-Mechanize-Plugin-JavaScript-0.007a/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Plugin/JavaScript.pm). Otherwise, I would recommend that you do all of this in a simple Python script. You will want to take a look at the [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib2#module-urllib2) module. For example, take a look at the following code (note that it uses cookielib to support cookies, which you will most likely need if your script requires you to be logged into a site):

```
import urllib2
import cookielib
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar()))
response = opener.open("http://twitter.com/someguy")
responseText = response.read()
```

Then you can do all of the processing you want using regular expressions.

Comment: The reason for wanting Greasemonkey is that the page to be crawled does not really approve of robots. Greasemonkey seemed like the easiest way to make the crawler look legitimate.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered Google Gears? That would give you access to a local SQLite database which you can store large amounts of information in.

Answer (score 1):

> The reason for wanting Greasemonkey
>   is that the page to be crawled does
>   not really approve of robots.
>   Greasemonkey seemed like the easiest
>   way to make the crawler look
>   legitimate.

Actually tainting your crawler through the browser does not make it that more legitimate. You are still breaking the terms of use of the site! WWW::Mechanize for example is equally well suited to 'spoof' your User Agent String, but that and crawling is, if the site does not allow spiders/crawlers, illegal!

Answer (score 0):

> The reason for wanting Greasemonkey is that the page to be crawled does not really approve of robots. Greasemonkey seemed like the easiest way to make the crawler look legitimate.

I think this is the the hardest way imaginable to make a crawler look legitimate.  Spoofing a web browser is trivially easy with some basic understanding of HTTP headers.

Also, some sites have heuristics that look for clients that behave like spiders, so simply making requests look like browser doesn't mean the won't know what you are doing.

Comment: I don't think setting the right headers is enough. You also have to load images, trigger AJAX requests and what not.